# Rolling Count in Power Query

Tags: excel, powerquery

Sorry if this question has been posted before but I couldn't seem to find anything that worked for me.

I am tring to set up a rolling count in Power query. I have a list of Permit Numbers, most of which are unique but some appear 2,3,4 ect.. times. I want to produce a column with a rolling count of these e.g on its first appearance in the list it is marked as '1' the second as '2' ect.....

The formula I have used in excel normally is COUNTIF($B$2:B2, B2) and then drag down and that works fine for what I need.

Comment: Would it be equivalent to a rolling sum by group? Check this post if so https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/How-to-do-a-running-Sum-by-group-in-Power-Query/td-p/290123

Comment: I could use something like that if I gave every row a 'cost' of '1' it would effectively do the same thing but not really the solution I was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to first group your data on the column with the Permit numbers. In the Grouping make sure to also add a column with 'All Data'.

This will result in a table showing the Unique Permit ID's and a column next to it with table objects. Then try to add an index row to the table object using Table.AddIndexColumn function https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-addindexcolumn. After having added this to each table object, expand the column with the table objects, and you have your rolling count :)

I hope to write a blogpost about this later. Hope this helped you out for now!

Rick

Comment: Is there a way to do the indexing for all Table objects in the column ?  My data has many rows and, more importantly, their number will change with new data, so can't really do this manually for each Table object in each row.  Thank you.